# How can I replace empty tags in beautifulsoup with a string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote this code to scrape some results from a website. However, after **scraping**, some tags appeared empty in my CSV file. How can I add a condition to replace the empty tags with a string containing a message?

This is a snippet of what my final CSV file looks like:

per|eng

lake|254

band|

raeson|541

news|5412

marks|225

nation|

case|474
.....

I want to add some condition to my loop so that if either object (per or eng) comes across an empty tag, then the condition replaces them with a string saying "no number" that makes my final result look like this:

per|eng

lake|254

band|no number

raeson|541

news|5412

marks|225

nation|no number

case|474
.....

I did some searching and I found that I should add a condition to my loop something like:

```
if per or eng == None:
  replace.(per and eng).replace("no number")
   else

    ........


records = []
for pg in range(1, 25 + 1):
    r = requests.get('url'+str(pg))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'itemprop':'url'})
    for result in results:
        per = result.find('strong').text.strip()
        eng = result.find('span').text.strip()

        records.append((per, eng))
        #sleep(randint(1, 4))

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['per', 'eng'])
df.to_csv('finaledata.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing anything in the DOM change it just before storing in file, see below code

```
records = []
for pg in range(1, 25 + 1):
    r = requests.get('url'+str(pg))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    results = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'itemprop':'url'})
    for result in results:
        per = result.find('strong').text.strip()
        if per=="":
            per="no number"
        eng = result.find('span').text.strip()
        if eng=="":
            eng="no number"

        records.append((per, eng))
        #sleep(randint(1, 4))

df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['per', 'eng'])
df.to_csv('finaledata.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep='|')
```